# ¿Cómo puedo sacar la variable más alta teniendo en cuenta que en cada programa los int son aleatorios del 1 al 20? #Java

Tags: java

Necesito printar mi variable con valor más alto en un switch. Ahora mismo tengo definidas 3 variables int aleatorias del 1 al 20, y quiero que me aparezca el número de la variable que haya sacado mayor valor. ¿podríais ayudarme? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentando y qué problemas/errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas más bien un for y una variable temporal:

```
int mayor = array[0];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(arra[i] > mayor){
        mayor = array[i];
    } 
}
```

Al terminar el bucle tendrás el mayor almacenado en la variable con el mismo nombre.